# Is it possible to share global variables between nodes?

Tags: ros, nodes, topic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in a situation where I need to track how many messages are in a Subscriber's Queue.  Since there's no straightforward size() function for the queue, I need to track both the amount of publishing and the amount of subscribing.  In other words, I am tracking how much one node -- let's call it PubNode -- can keep up with another node -- let's call it SubNode.  I've tried to create a brand new node that will track both PubNode and SubNode, but in practice it seems to create unnecessary overhead.

To resolve this, I want to create a "PubNode counter" that SubNode can access.  Is it possible to create global variables that two separate nodes can access?  It seems that PubNode and SubNode would have to be linked, but I'm pretty sure this isn't possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67275/is-it-possible-to-share-global-variables-between-nodes?/) by [Toletum](https://answers.ros.org/users/5178/toletum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2013-07-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-07-15**:
A more radical suggestion might be to simply use the callback to copy the incoming message to a local queue.  If this is fast, then you shouldn't end up with (m)any messages on the subscriber queue.  Then, you have direct access to the local queue.  Of course, there's copy overhead.

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-07-15**:
Given that you now have your publisher listening to your subscriber, have you looked into using a service for the subscriber to request the next message? Another alternative, depending on the rest of your design specs, would be for the subscriber to implement a queue_size service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for all the suggestions.  In the end, I had my Subscriber publish a "confirmation message" back to the Publisher.  That way, the Publishing Node could always keep track of both the number of messages sent as well as the number of messages that were received.

The difference of "sent minus received" then provides the current Queue size (unless of course the Queue overflows, but that's another matter entirely).

---

Originally posted by [Toletum](https://answers.ros.org/users/5178/toletum/) with karma: 195 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-16**:
Sending acknowledgements is a reasonable design. Messages could get lost, so the answer may not be exact.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it seems to me - no. Nodes - are different processes.

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2013-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you could create a service call where the publisher can ask the subscriber how many items in your queue, but i am not sure how to check the size of the message buffer

---

Originally posted by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) with karma: 418 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you can use the parameter server... ["Nodes [...] communicate with one another using streaming topics, RPC services, and the ***Parameter Server***."](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Nodes)

EDIT: In order to mantain modularity and independent nodes, you can modify (increment?) a parameter '/pub_counter' everytime you publish on a topic. On the other side you can check this parameter within your callback function.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use a shared memory buffer if you really want to have a shared global state.  Or, you could publish the number of messages published on a separate topic.  Anyone interested could subscribe to that topic.  In the callback, you would copy the number from the message into a local variable, and this should (most of the time) correspond to the actual number of sent messages, from which you can calculate the number in the queue.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1